# Javascript : Assign a function and pass parameter at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have html buttons "classA","classB" and "classC" to which I assign the onclick handler function as follows..

```
var classA = document.getElementById('classA');
classA.onclick = filterByClassA;

var classB = document.getElementById('classB');
classB.onclick = filterByClassB;

var classC = document.getElementById('classC');
classC.onclick = filterByClassC;
```

These 3 functions do the same thing, only difference being the class. 
So, can I have a single function assigned to these buttons, called with different parameters for each button. Something like below

```
var classA = document.getElementById('classA');
classA.onclick = filterByClass('classA');

var classB = document.getElementById('classB');
classB.onclick = filterByClass('classB');

var classC = document.getElementById('classC');
classC.onclick = filterByClass('classC');
```

I know this is a function call and not assignment and this is wrong but is there a way I can achieve this i.e. assign a function and pass parameter at the same time but not call it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function filterByClass(className)
{

    return function()
    {
        // Do something with className
        console.log(className);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about the downvote, but `return function(event) {console.log(className);}` can be useful to op.

Comment: I would suggest renaming the outer function. The base idea is correct, however.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, I followed the naming that the poster gave. "filterByClass('classC');"

Comment: @Tamil Vendham, It would indeed :)

Answer (score 3):

[Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) can help you out here: Its called partial application.

### Bind Syntax

`fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

- 1st param is scope of the function when it is called.
- From 2nd you can pass any number of agruments. See the below code to know how it works.

### Code:

```
var classA = document.getElementById('classA');
classA.onclick = filterByClass.bind(classA, 'classA');

var classB = document.getElementById('classB');
classB.onclick = filterByClass.bind(classB, 'classB');

var classC = document.getElementById('classC');
classC.onclick = filterByClass.bind(classC, 'classC');

function filterByClass(className, eventObject) {
  console.log(this, className, eventObject);
}
```

### Update:

Check out the `Compatibility` section in the above MDN link. You may need to use it, if you are going to use `bind` in non modern browsers.

Comment: @Tamil Vendhan, will try this approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

i always try to keep the code as short as possible

so if your buttons are inside a container you can do that.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>atest</title>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 var c=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].childNodes,
 l=c.length,
 filterByClass=function(){
  console.log(this.id);//this.id is the classA or whatever
 };
 while(l--){
  c[l].onclick=filterByClass;
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <button id="classA">A</button>
 <button id="classB">B</button>
 <button id="classC">C</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in this case

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
```

returns the first div in the document

```
childNodes
```

give u the list of the buttons inside that div

the while function adds the onclick event with your function 'filterByClass'

inside filterByClass u can access the element by `this` and so return it's `id` with `this.id`

Comment: "i always try to keep the code as short as possible" - cocco.
Why? this is development code, you are just making it more difficult for yourself and others to read and understand. Code will be shortened/compressed when it is put through a minifier. (prior to production)

Comment: i mean: if u write 5 times getelementbyid ... also the compressor will write 5 times getelementbyid... he doesn't know that he can replace that with a superfast while loop caching the parentnode.it also keeps all the useless variables that u manually create.why pass a variable to a function if u can access it directly?

Comment: this script also breaks every circular reference and so does not create any type of memoryleak.

Comment: I was specifically commenting on your "i always try to keep the code as short as possible", that's why I quoted it.